# Is it possible to run two nodes in elasticsearch but only allow querying on one?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elastic search cluster set up with two nodes. We want the second node only for replication as load isn't enough to warrant a second node. All primary shards are on the master.

Now here's the problem, every *other* query gets forwarded to the secondary node. As a result, query times are doubled. I expect this is due to elasticsearch's load balancing.

Is there a way to prevent queries from being delegated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify `preference=_local` on the search request url, the request will be executed on the node that received the request (assuming that this node has required shards allocated on it). See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/preference/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!